# Automatic emails with report as attachment in Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I want to send automatic emails to the persons whose emailID will be stored in the fields of a query with my report (same to everyone) as attachment.

1. I have the query, during compiling it is showing error message "in query expression.

   > Error 3075
2. I need to attach my report with every email, but I am not finding a way to delete every time after sending from my local file (**I have removed the code related to this, so you can add a new one**)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub sendserialemail()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim emailto As String
Dim emailcc As String
Dim emailsubject As String
Dim emailtext As String
Dim outapp As Outlook.Application
Dim outmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outstarted As Boolean
Dim rpt As Report
Dim pdfmail As String

On Error Resume Next
Set outapp = GetObject(, "outlook.application")
On Error GoTo 0
If outapp Is Nothing Then
    Set outapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    outstarted = True
End If

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryeMailOverdueTasks")
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "tasks", acFormatPDF, "desktop"
Do Until rs.EOF
    emailto = rs.Fields("responsible person").Value

    emailcc = "ravikumar.ramadas@plansee.com"

    emailsubject = "Pending tasks to complete the issue regarding" & " " & rs.Fields("issue").Value

    emailtext = "Hello" & vbCrLf & "Kindly complete the task which is in the attached file to complete the cutomer isue regarding" & " " & rs.Fields("issue").Value
pdfmail = "tasks.pdf"

    Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    outmail.To = emailto
    outmail.CC = emailcc
    outmail.Subject = emailsubject
    outmail.Body = emailtext
    outmail.Attachments = pdfmail
    outmail.Send

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

If outstarted Then
    outapp.Quit
End If

Set outmail = Nothing
Set outapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `SELECT Issue,[Responsible Person] FROM qryeMailOverdueTasks`

Comment: "I have removed the code related to this , so you can add a new one" - it's better if you include the code which is giving you problems, and explain what the exact problem is.

Comment: Hello , Thank you for your reply , I am new to this website & I didn't know how to reply with new code , hence I updated the existing code with the failed attachment code portion. The error I am getting is  - "error 5 , invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: Your question narrative still says problem code was removed. Which line triggers error? Code tries to save a pdf named "desktop" to folder db is located in. Then code tries to attach a file named "tasks.pdf" but this file does not exist nor does this specify file path where pdf is located.

Comment: Ohh now I got where I did wrong , thank you explaining what actually it was doing , I renamed them & now it is  working .Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code tries to save a pdf named "desktop" to folder db is located in. Then code tries to attach a file named "tasks.pdf" but this file does not exist nor does this specify file path where pdf is located.

Correct code to specify file path and name to save and retrieve.